# javafx mediaview white flash on transition

Tags: javafx-8, media

Folks...

I'm using the following code to transition between two videos.

```
public void loadMedia(Media media)
{
    MediaPlayer newPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    newPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    mediaView.setMediaPlayer(newPlayer);
    player = newPlayer;
}
```

When I call loadMedia with the new video, the mediaplayer flashes white briefly. I'm guessing this has to do with the status taking time. But I need these transitions to go smoothly with no flash.

What to do?

Thanks,
GeePaw

Answer (score 0):

As so often, I answered my own question shortly after. The trick is to wait for the status to be ready before you change the view's player:

```
public void loadMedia(Media media)
{
    MediaPlayer newPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    newPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    newPlayer.setOnReady(()->videoReady(newPlayer));
}

private void videoReady(MediaPlayer newPlayer)
{
    mediaView.setMediaPlayer(newPlayer);
    player = newPlayer;
}
```

Comment: Your answer almost saved my day. Im having trouble to adapt to my needs, at the end of the video, i must find the next one and play it, it works.. i have the same problem as yours, a white flick between the files, i tryed to adapt your solution, but got nothing... any chance you elaborate more?

as far as i got with your answer i still have the same white flick. 
(code at -> https://pastebin.com/0jej1rrF) the carregaVideos(),update the 'this.url' string, to the next file to be played.

thanks for your time!